# Buttons on navigation bar do not pick up window tint colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

### Note, I've recently come back to this and it seems to have been fixed in more recent versions of the SDK, without me having to implement anything except the code in the question.  Many thanks to all who answered.

I have an Objective-C app that runs on the iPad and displays a view controller with a modal presentation style of `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`:

```
UINavigationController *editorNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editorViewController];
editorNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[navigationController presentViewController:editorNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When this view controller is displayed the buttons in the navigation bar are purple, which I assume has been picked up from the window's tint colour, which is what I want.

Later I need to display another view controller over the top, that fills the whole window:

```
UINavigationController *previewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myPreviewViewController];
[owningViewController presentViewController:previewNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem I have is that when `myPreviewController` is displayed, the buttons in the navigation bar are grey.  I've tried reinstating the colour on the new navigation controller:

```
previewNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:123/255.0 green:26/255.0 blue:69/255.0 alpha:1];
```

but without any joy.

How can I get the buttons to have the correct colour?  Can I get the new navigation controller to pick up the window tint colour automatically, or do I have to set it explicitly?  Is this something to do with presenting the second navigation controller over the top of one that uses `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`?

Any help much appreciated!  Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Any screenshots? Maybe...

Comment: try setting `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor` in `myPreviewViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks @kambala but unfortunately that didn't fix it.

Comment: Have you tried using the ios apperance method? Like:     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

Comment: Thanks @Alexander but that didn't fix it either.  I tried calling setTintColor in the app delegate and immediately before presenting the new navigation controller, but still no joy.

Comment: @Sascha Held what is `owningViewController ` in your case , the viewcontroller which you have presented from the first viewcontroller?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the navigationBar translucent and transparent.
In view `Will Appear`:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Than create a UIView with frame size of navigationBar `(CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.height,22)` and create buttons on it with color you need.
I know, thats a crutch but should work)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the appearance of the `UIBarButtonItem` globally so all `UINavigationControllers` will share the same design:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:16.0f],NSFontAttributeName,
                                                          nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Additionally you could also change the `[UINavigationBar appearance]`:

```
//The setTintColor would tint the < Back button in the NavigationBar 
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]}];
```

This code can be add it before presenting the `UIViewControllers` or simply in the `AppDelegate.m`.